# html select tag: on select get value from another select tag

Tags: html, function, select

I have two Select tags : the first one is dynamically populated with a php script (scans my non-empty folders) and give me the country codes as below:

```
         <select name="countries" id="countries"> 
         <option>fr</option>
         <option>gr</option>
         <option>it</option>
         <option>gr</option>
         <option>pl</option>
         <option>gb</option>
         <option>es</option>
         <option>pt</option>
                  ... 
         (dynamically populated from a php script)
    </select>
```

and the second SELECT is a full list  of countrie with their codes already populated:

```
    <select name="ctCodes" id="ctCodes">
    <option>--select--</option>
    <option value="fr">France</option>
    <option value="nl">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="bl">Belgium</option>
    <option value="rs">Russia</option>
                   ... 
      (full ready list with all countries and code as value)
    </select>
```

I don't want that my visitor choose from the first SELECT because it is just codes (fr, de, ..) but I want him to choose from a more comprehensive list with full name country (France, Germany..) where the options values will redirect him to the selected country : Ex he selects Germany, my function will take him : location.href = "xxx.php#" + element.value;) in this case 'de'.

How can I realize this: Create a Third SELECT tag which OPTIONS are added from the full dropdown list according to the first one ? ..is there a solution to just filter the fullname list in the 2nd SELECT tAG to keep only Options which are loaded in the first one ?  ...I know that's a nano second job for sql or ms-access !.. but is it possible to do it with html and javascript?
I am gratefull for all answers.

Comment: Where do you want that data and what are you working with? A Javascript function, submitted data (POST request) in PHP, maybe something else?

Comment: It's about two lists (select tags), the first is populated from a php (works just fine) and the second is a full list of all countries with their codes as 'values'

Comment: I want just when I select an option from the first select I get the value from the second list .. to load a specific html page: Something like function clic(element)
{
 objForm = document.MyForm;
 location.href = "xxx.php#" + element.value; (this value must be the country code picked from the full list)
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first `select` with id `#country`

```
var e = document.getElementById("country");
var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

In this code `value` will contain the  `country name` if it is the value.

```
var textVar = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
```

If the name of the country is the `text` it will be stored in `textVar`

Now you want to auto select the second select use `onchange` with the select having id `country`.

Now  in the second select with id `ctCodes`

```
var element = document.getElementById('ctCodes');
element.value = value;
```

Use this code to set the value of  select.